# Multiline recursive grep in Bash

Tags: bash, grep

Is there any way to make this regex work in bash ?:

```
INSERT(\n|[^;])*;
```

This would allow me to find any INSERT sql statement in a file.
But, with "*grep*" i can't find them if they are not on 1 single line and "*pcregrep*" will not approve the `[^;]` part.

Is there any other "*grep*" or maybe an other regexp ? I have searched in the other threads but I can't manage to find the answer.

Thank you in advance for your contribution or a link with the answer.

Comment: `awk` allows you to change the record separator so you treat the entire file as a single record.

Comment: `pcregrep -M  'INSERT(\n|[^;])*;' /tmp/file`  works fine by me here, `pcregrep version 8.38 2015-11-23`

Comment: `grep` is not part of bash, and its behavior does not change depending on which shell (or non-shell utility) it's invoked with; a given version of grep will behave just the same way if invoked with the same arguments on a system that doesn't even have bash installed. Its behavior *does* change depending on which version of grep you have (thus, who your OS vendor is) -- but there's no reason for this to be tagged `bash`. Perhaps you want `unix` (as it's a POSIX-specified standard utility)?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes I should have used a unix tag, thanks to point that out.

Comment: @Wrikken: I get this type of error:

`pcregrep: error -8 means that a resource limit was exceeded
pcregrep: check your regex for nested unlimited loops
pcregrep: pcre_exec() error -8 while matching this line:
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+`

Comment: @GrégoryDesprez, it's pretty obvious *why* that line is unacceptably expensive for a PCRE engine to match (particularly when matching it against a longer line of dashes) -- you probably shouldn't be trying to parse that particular data as a regex (need to filter out the header from input?) -- or at least escaping the `+`s so they aren't interpreted to mean "one-or-more of the prior".

Comment: (see https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html for background on the difference in performance and space requirements between PCRE and traditional Thompson NFA regex engines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk` as @Barmar says.

A simple command to extract all `INSERT`s as above is:

```
 awk '/INSERT/,/;/' filename
```

This matches all text from INSERT to the first subsequent semicolon. 
This assumes you want a case-sensitive search and that you are sure that all INSERTS are correctly semicolon terminated.

Comment: This is case-SENSITIVE, not case-iNSENSITIVE

Comment: Thanks for this, I did not think to use awk this way.